# Tomcat 6.0.18 service will not start on a windows server

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-server-2003

I installed Tomcat 6.0.18 on a windows server 2003 box and it will not start as a service.
I'm running it with jdk 1.6.0_07.

It runs when I start it with tomcat6.exe.

I got a vague error in the System Event Log on Windows.

The Apache Tomcat 6 service terminated with service-specific error 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll bite it :-)

Tomcat Service on windows is dependent on the MS C Runtime library msvcr71.dll. As long as it is in the path, the service will start just fine.

Just to prevent your other windows to be forced to use this version of the runtime library, you might want to copy the DLL to just the tomcat bin path instead of windows\system32.

Comment: If by launching Tomcat monitor you find you are pointing to a location where there is jvm.dll, like jre/server/jvm.dll, copy the dll where you have the jvm.dll.

Answer (score 3):

From [gobaco.wordpress.com](http://gobaco.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/could-not-start-tomcat-6-on-windows-xp/)

Tomcat 6 couldn’t find a file called msvcr71.dll.
I just copied it over from
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322
to
c:\windows\system32

and was able to start tomcat.

I thought this was very strange, so I wanted to post it on SO in case anyone else runs into this problem. If someone wants to post the same answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I have posted similar answer below :-)

Answer (score 2):

i follow the above guide but still the same, error 0, 
my process monitor log at  http://www.sendspace.com/file/t0tahr

Comment: i post my solution at
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.tomcat.user/184218

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same problem enabling the default java virtual machine in the configuration app.

Assuming you have installed tomcat using:

```
service install tomcat-6.0.35
```

execute:

```
tomcat6w //ES/tomcat-6.0.35
```

a window pops up, select the java tab and click on "Use default" checkbox.

The service install script (I immagine) selected `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll` instead.

Environment:

- Windows Server standard SP2 64-bin
- Java 1.6.0_23-b05 (Java hotspot 64-bit server vm 19.0-b09 mixed mode)
- Apache tomcat 6.35 (you guessed this didn't you?)

Answer (score 1):

I copied the msvcr71.dll from the java home directory to the bin directory of the apache-tomcat install, and the service started after that.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's an older post, I thought I'd share the knowledge about the very same issue I had, but the workaround was different.

> The Apache Tomcat 7 service terminated with service-specific error 0 (0x0).

As there was no more information regarding the problem I went back to the Tomcat Control Panel and had a look at the Java path, which was pointed to an earlier installation of Java Virtual Machine:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll, which no longer existed, so I had to change the JRE version to jre7.

Having done that, the service started up and all running now.

Hope it'll help some of you out there.